# jquery multiple link selection, to show divs

Tags: jquery

I have 5 textlinks and 5 to container. now I want to build a filter. and that if I want a link click it the right div will be displayed or just hidden. that's not the problem, but how can I select multiple links, so a multiple selection. because someone has an idea?

very simple...
http://jsfiddle.net/6Eqmg/

```
    $( ".herrenberg" ).click(function() {
  $( "#herrenberg" ).toggle();
});
$( ".heimat" ).click(function() {
  $( "#heimat" ).toggle();
});
$( ".menschen" ).click(function() {
  $( "#menschen" ).toggle();
});
$( ".tragbares" ).click(function() {
  $( "#tragbares" ).toggle();
});
$( ".kunst" ).click(function() {
  $( "#kunst" ).toggle();
});
$( ".taschen" ).click(function() {
  $( "#taschen" ).toggle();
});
$( ".kruscht" ).click(function() {
  $( "#kruscht" ).toggle();
});
$( ".wohn" ).click(function() {
  $( "#wohn" ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Please show your current HTML and JS code

Comment: how do we know without looking into your codes?

Comment: if you want to show/hide multiple div on a group of link then assign them same class & write your code by selecting those class

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should give a class to those link.
In the jfiddle you linked I saw you gave those link a class :

```
blabla class="tragbares" ... blabla
```

I have to warn you that if that name is supposed to be unique, it is better to assign that name to *id* attribute.
The *class* attribute does what you asked in this question: select multiple objects of the DOM.

**ANSWER TO COMMENT:** I mean that if you have to access to a single element of the DOM, HTML gives you the *id* attribute. While if you have to access to a group of elements HTML gives you the *class* attribute

Comment: that was only on the fast because I had no better idea.
is the better way to work with id's and anchor?